# Java holding 3 values in array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

I need a array object, that should holds 3 Objects.

At first was using `Collection`, but I need to add to a specific place. for example:

```
CollectionObject.add(pos, myObject)
```

Then I went to `ArrayList`, created object like this:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> array = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

When creating this, it creats array with size 1, but I need to add to position 0-2, so adding like:

```
array.add(2, myObject)
```

I got :

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
```

My solution is, create arraylist, add 3 empty objects to it, and later overwrite, but any more subtle solution? Are there any better array holding objects, like `Vector` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of 3 elements instead as follows:

```
MyObject [] array = new MyObject[3];
array[2] = myObject;
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not an array, it is a `List` implemented using a hidden array. You need to add three items to it before you can address items by index, like this:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> array = new ArrayList<MyObject>(3);
array.add(null);
array.add(null);
array.add(null);
array.set(2, myObject)
```

`ArrayList`s grow automatically. If you do not need this functionality, you use a plain array, for example, like this:

```
MyObject array = new MyObject[] {myObject1, myObject2, myObject3};
```

Now you can replace items by using the indexing operator:

```
array[2] = newMyObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObject[] a = new MyObject[3];
a[2] = new MyObject();
```